# Install Module on PostgreSQL (Windows)

Tags: windows, postgresql, module

I am a new user of PostgreSQL. I want to install module on it. But I don't know how to do it. My computer has a windows system.

After some research, I got to know that we can install module with terminal/command line on Linux/Mac system. But how to do it on Windows system?

Can anybody tell me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Which module? Some are pre-compiled, making life easier on Windows. Otherwise you'll want to learn MinGW, which makes it easy to compile C extensions on Windows

Comment: it is Tablefunc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.1 we have the [CREATE EXTENSION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) command to do this in a transparent way (AKA without editing config file and etc.):

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Comment: I also use pgAdmin3.

Comment: You can do with both, psql or pgAdmin. What's the PostgreSQL version you're using? Which extension you want to install?

Comment: You want to install tablefunc, right? So I edited my answer to comply with this.

Comment: I use pgAdmin 3. I want to install tablefunc module.

Comment: So you just need to connect in your database through PgAdmin3 and issue the command in above answer.

Comment: I succeed. Thank you.